# Python - Calculating Percent of Grand Total in Pivot Tables

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, percentage

I have a dataframe that I converted to a pivot table using pd.pivot_table method and a sum aggregate function:

```
summary = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                         index=["Region"], 
                         columns=["Product"], 
                         values=['Price'],
                         aggfunc=[np.sum],
                         fill_value=0,
                         margins=True,
                         margins_name="Total"
                        )
```

I have received an output like this:

[image: Sample Pivot Table]

I would like to add another pivot table that displays percent of grand total calculated in the previous pivot table for each of the categories. All these should add up to 100% and should look like this.

[image: Pivot Table with percents of Grand Total]

I have tried the following workaround that I found on stackoverflow:

```
total = df['Price'].sum()

table = pd.pivot_table(DF, 
                       index=["Region"],
                       columns=["Product"], 
                       values=['Price'],
                       aggfunc=[np.sum, 
                                (lambda x: sum(x)/total*100)
                               ],
                       fill_value=0,
                       margins=True,
                       margins_name="Total"
                      )
```

This calculated the percentages but they only add up to 85%...

It'd be great to not have to calculate the total outside of the pivot tabe and just be able to call the Grand Total from the first pivot. But even if I have to calculate separately, like in the code above, as long as it adds up to 100% it would still be great.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you addd the text version of the table.

Comment: Also show us how the df data looks like than the pivot table output

Comment: Dark, sales was just an example to show what I'm trying to do. I work with highly sensitive data that I cannot share. As a python beginner, any time something goes wrong, I think it's my code. But your question make me look closer at my data. I had some missing values that resulted in some records being excluded from the pivot tables but the Total calculated separately had all the records included. That's why my numbers did not match. Once I excluded the records with the missing values from the Total calculation, everything worked. Thank you for making me think about the data integrity first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done very easily:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    # Create table
    table_1 = np.matrix([[100, 200, 650, 950],
                         [200, 250, 350, 800],
                         [400, 500, 200, 200],
                         [700, 950, 1200, 2850]])

    column_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Region Total']
    idx_labels = ['Region 1', 'Region 2', 'Region 3', 'Product Total']

    df = pd.DataFrame(table_1)
    df.columns = column_labels
    df.index = idx_labels
    df.index.name = 'Sales'

    # Create percentage table
    df_percentage = np.round(df*100/df.iloc[-1, -1], 1)

    print(df_percentage)

                      A     B     C  Region Total
    Sales                                        
    Region 1        3.5   7.0  22.8          33.3
    Region 2        7.0   8.8  12.3          28.1
    Region 3       14.0  17.5   7.0           7.0
    Product Total  24.6  33.3  42.1         100.0
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. When I try converting pivot table to dataframe using the same columns and index that I used for creating pivot table, I get an error: "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 7 elements, new values have 5 elements"... I checked my data, not sure what's wrong..

Comment: Are you trying to unpivot your pivot table? I am not sure why you would want to do this. The point of the sulution I have posted is that once you have created the pivot table (which is also of data frame type) it is much more efficient calculate the percentages by dividing the whole pivot table by the Product Total than to achieve it by another pivot operation. Since the ProductTotal is the last element of the table its coordinates are [-1, -1] and it is easy to specify it in mathematical operations. So, as long as your first pivot works you are probably fine.

Comment: If you look at the code above most of it is there in order to create the table. The calculation of the percentages is one short line of code: df_percentage = np.round(df*100/df.iloc[-1, -1], 1). Therefore if you had posted the table as text I would have posted back only this line and the print command.

Comment: :) I see. I thought I needed to convert the pivot table to data frame first before I could use the code from last line. I didn't realize pivot table was already a data frame. I tried the code on my table and it worked perfectly! Was exactly what i was trying to do without having to calculate totals outside the table since I already had them in the table. So, then do I understand correctly that I can use df.iloc[x, y] to locate any value in the table? And can I reference the values by by row/column names instead of indexes?

Comment: You can indeed use df.iloc[row_index, column_index] to locate any value in a data frame. And do bear in mind the zero indexing. -1 is a special coordinate meaning the last element. You can use labels instead of numerical coordinates in the df.loc[row_label, column_label] function. It is worth checking the description of these functions in order to also learn how to select not just individual cells but also ranges and to know how to return values in a series or data frame format. And please whenever possible post data as text not images. Or you might not get help next time.

Comment: Perfect. This saved me a lot of work. Sorry about the images. Will make sure to post text next time. Thank you for all your help!